# Google Cloud Dataflow (Python SDK) : Workflow failed | Each time the worker process eventually lost contact with the service

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have built a workflow ingesting data from Google Cloud Storage, performing transformations in a ParDo and Dumping the output to  BigQuery.

```
import apache_beam as beam
import logging

class ParseValidateRecordDoFn(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, context):
        # All transformations come here    
        return custom_object

        try: 
            data = json.loads(context)
            yield beam.pvalue.TaggedOutput('PASS', data)

        except:
            print "ERROR"
            yield beam.pvalue.TaggedOutput('ERROR', context)

job_name = JOB_NAME
project = PROJECT_NAME
staging_location = STAGING_LOCATION
temp_location = TEMP_LOCATION

p = beam.Pipeline(argv=[
        '--job_name', job_name,
        '--project', project,
        '--staging_location', staging_location,
        '--temp_location', temp_location,
        '--no_save_main_session',
        '--runner', 'DataflowRunner',
        '--num_workers', '25',
        '--requirements_file', 'requirements.txt'])

text = p | "Reading Source" >> beam.io.ReadFromText('SOURCE LOCATION')

output_validate = text | beam.ParDo(ParseValidateRecordDoFn()).with_outputs('PASS','ERROR', main='main')

(output_validate.PASS | "Writing to BQ" >> beam.io.Write(beam.io.BigQuerySink('Table_name',
                                      create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_NEVER,
                                      write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND, validate=True)))


(output_validate.ERROR | "Writing UNPARSED File" >> beam.io.WriteToText('ERROR_LOCATION'))

logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
p.run().wait_until_finish()
```

Since this week, The code has started throwing error:

[Error Message Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riah3.png)

Error Stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 778, in run
    deferred_exception_details=deferred_exception_details)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 630, in do_work
    exception_details=exception_details)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/utils/retry.py", line 168, in wrapper
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 491, in report_completion_status
    exception_details=exception_details)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 299, in report_status
    work_executor=self._work_executor)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/workerapiclient.py", line 342, in report_status
    append_counter(work_item_status, counter)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/workerapiclient.py", line 38, in append_counter
    if isinstance(counter.name, counters.CounterName):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CounterName'
```

Things I have tried:

- Breaking the code down to the most nascent form.
- Removing IO operation to local directories for debugging
- Trying Hello World code on DF Runner
- Switched to high memory workers

None of the above resulted in Success, all of them threw the same error as:
A workitem was attempted 4 times without success. Each time the worker eventually lost contact with the service.

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: The `A workitem was attempted 4 times without success. Each time the worker eventually lost contact with the service` error is just an error dataflow throws after an internal error occured.
The `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CounterName'` is the original error on which the job fails. This looks like a problem with package versions.

Comment: What SDK you are have (name & version) installed? Do you also have the same SDK in the requirements.txt file? As Robbe said, this looks like a version mismatch issue.

Comment: I am using the Apache Beam Python SDK (2.2.0)
Yes, same version is mentioned in requirements.txt
Also, upon further analysis of logs, I got to know that Pandas is taking too long to install on the worker processes, Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Could you do a pip list in your virtual environment and share the output?

Comment: How are you installing Beam on your environment? Via pip? What pip command are you using? Or perhaps via source?

Comment: I had the same problem, but in my case this was due to setup.py requiring an older version of apache-beam. Removing that fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

The same code is working on the local machine in DirectRunner without issues. When we remove the reference to PANDAS section of this code, the code is executing without any issues.